# Pop up a message in vba

Tags: vba, excel, range

I am working on a file which in one sheet lets call it summary, I have formula that calculate the values which Ienter manually in other sheets, so I want to have an vba code to notify me by pop up message that the calculation result in summary sheet is <=0 when doing data entry in other sheets.
I have found below code which works fine with only one cell but if I want to extend it to other cells in the same row results in error. Suppose I want to extend it to *B9:CZ9*.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Me.Range("B9").Value <= 0 Then _
        MsgBox "Leave is finished!"
End Sub
```

Comment: The [Microsoft Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193(v=office.15).aspx) have an example of what you want to do and how to do it, have you tried to search for it before posting this?

Answer (score 0):

Possible background:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    With Me.Range("B9:CZ9")
        If Application.CountIf(.Cells, "<=0") = .Cells.Count Then _
            MsgBox "Leave is finished!"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for the edit and answer, I used it but nothing happened

Comment: "It happened" only if all cells in range `B9:CZ9` less or equal to `0`

Comment: I forgot to add that in range B9:CZ9 I have formula which sum values from other sheets which i do data entry manually, does it affect the vba code?

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    For Each cl In Me.Range("B9:CZ9")
        If cl.Value <= 0 Then 
            MsgBox "Leave is finished!"
        End If
    Next cl 
End Sub

Comment: they are the same exept that your code allows blank cells (because they are treated as 0)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim RNG As Range
    Set RNG = Selection
    For Each c In RNG
        If c.Value <= 0 Then
            MsgBox "Leave is finished!"
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Please see this FAQ for [Formatting Code Blocks and other markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Also, please consider adding some explanation with your code to avoid down votes.

Comment: Also, your code won't compile if you're using `Option Explicit` (and you should be).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, maybe this code helps you (you have to put this code to the source of the correct worksheet you want to work this code on):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim leave As Boolean: leave = False
    For Each c In Me.Range("B9:CZ9").Cells
        If c.Value <= 0 Then: leave = True
    Next
    If leave Then: MsgBox "Leave is finished!"
End Sub
```

This code works when something is calculated in a cell, for example when you type `=0` into any of them, and don't give you lots of messageboxes.

If you want this to work when anything changes, use `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

Remember that extension `xlsx` cannot contain VBA codes. Therefore after implementing the code to the worksheet you want this code works on, you have to [save it as macro-enabled workbook](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/saving-and-using-an-excel-2010-macroenabled-workbo.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, but again something wrong, can I send you my file so you will see the original file and I can explain it to you.

Comment: @Trapeze2011 Yes, please, upload it to somewhere and give a link to it. And could you add more details to what is your problem exactly? You can edit your question above.

Comment: @Trapeze2011 I edited the answer as I examined your excel file. The xlsm version is [here](http://speedy.sh/TS9WG/database.xlsm)